# Writing simple text pdf file using delphi synpdf

Tags: delphi, pdf

I want to write simple text pdf file and I use Synopse pdf Delphi library.
Is it possible to write one text line to file and it automatically insert new line to file without using coordinates?

Comment: Inset new line with line break.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to use the [mORMotReport.pas unit](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SQLite3/mORMotReport.pas).

It is very easy to add some text, with automatic insert of lines, and page layout.

See [this sample folder](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/tree/master/SQLite3/Samples/05%20-%20Report%20created%20from%20code) as reference.